# How html5 canvas tag works with asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

> I have an asp.net mvc web application. Here in 1 module I want to show
>   a signature pad for the user to have electronic signature whatever he
>   uses either a mouse or a touch pad(Ipad etc). I am referring to the
>   tutorial of Thomas Bradley which is as :

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/accept/

> The problem which I am facing is that though mvc supports HTML 5,
>   still my mvc 3 app code does not recognize HTML tags due to which I am
>   not able to draw my signature . Am I missing some dll, script or other
>   reference? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It won't recognize it in visual studio 2010 but it should work in a browser

Comment: @Kyle It doesn't works on browser as well. The canvas box is also not created where I can draw signature.

Comment: In this case, can you post your code? It's hard to help without it.

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli I have taken the code from 
http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/accept/
See if it helps.

Comment: @ShalinJirawla, without YOUR code I can't help you with YOUR errors. Looking at the plugin's page (http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) there's a section describing "How to Use the Plugin", make sure you have followed all steps. This plugin is pure javascript, you will not have problems by using it on your MVC page. Also, make sure your doctype is correct (<!DOCTYPE html>).

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle said, in older versions of Visual Studio you will not have syntax support for HTML 5 tags.

But it will work on the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is not a browser, so MVC Razor engine just can generate the html5 code and as comments suggest you Visual Studio may not necessarily recognize the tags and show the syntax errors. But all the modern browsers supporting html5 will surely support it.

So keep coding and test it in browser.